# Modelo HTML em javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estou com um problema para atribuir uma função à um **input**

possuo 2 modelos HTML em javaScript

```
var forgotPassword = ' <form action="#">'+
                            '<fieldset>'+
                                '<legend class="title"><span class="lang" key = "SendmePassword">Send me password</span></legend>'+
                                    '<div class="input_block">'+
                                        '<div class="input_wrap">'+
                                            '<input type="text" id="sing_email" class="input" placeholder="Email">'+
                                            '<label for="sing_email" class="label_mail"></label>'+
                                        '</div>'+
                                        '<p>Enter a valid e-mail, the password will be sent to you  </p>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                '<input type="submit" value="Sing IN" class="btn btn_red" id="backtoSingIN">'+
                                '<input type="submit" value="Send" class="btnSend btn_red" id="send">'+
                            '</fieldset>'+
                        '</form>';

//======================
var singIN = '<form action="#">'+
                '<fieldset>'+
                    '<legend class="title"><span class="lang" key = "LogIn">SING IN</span></legend>'+
                    '<div class="input_block">'+
                        '<div class="input_wrap">'+
                            '<input type="text" id="mail" class="input" placeholder="Email">'+
                            '<label for="mail" class="label_mail"></label>'+

                        '</div>'+
                        '<div class="input_wrap">'+
                            '<input type="text" id="pass" class="input" placeholder="Password">'+
                            '<label for="pass" class="label_pass"></label>'+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<a href="#" class="forgotPass" id="forgot"><span class="lang" key ="ForgotPassword">Forgot password</span>?</a>'+
                    '<input type="submit" value="Sing IN" class="btn btn_red">'+
                '</fieldset>'+
            '</form>';
//================================================================================================================================================
function loadSingIN(){
    return singIN;
}


function loadForgotPassword(){
    return forgotPassword;
}
```

consigo utilizar os 2 modelos dessa forma

```
//LOAD FORGOT PASSWORD
document.getElementById("forgot").addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log("fui clicado");
    document.getElementById("root").innerHTML = loadForgotPassword();
});


    document.getElementById("send").addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log("fui clicado");
    document.getElementById("root").innerHTML = loadSingIN();
    });
```

porém quando tento atribuir uma função de click ao meu **input com id "send"**

ele me retorna um erro no console

> Erro:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of
>   null

Já tentei usar o $(ducument).ready mas não consegui resolver, alguém poderia me ajudar ?

Comment: Este erro e exibido pois não existe o **input com id "send"** no momento em que o JavaScript é executado. Em que parte do código seu HTML é montado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece porque você está adicionando um evento há um elemento que ainda não foi anexado a árvore do documento (`DOM`) e portanto **"ainda não existe"**.

O seguinte "exemplo minimo" reproduz o mesmo erro:

```js
let model = `<h1 id="header">Hello World</h1>`


document.getElementById('header').addEventListenner('click', console.log, true)
```

Aparentemente você está trabalhando com a ideia de mostrar e ocultar dois formulários dinâmicos, alternando entre ambos.

Uma abordagem mais concisa seria mostrar um formulário por padrão e ocultá-lo e mostrar o outro e vice-e-versa ... o seguinte "exemplo minimo" mostra isto:

```js
// link para recuperação
let forgot = document.getElementById("forgot")
// link para login
let signin = document.getElementById('backtoSingIN')
// formulário de login
let formSignin = document.getElementById('signin-form')
// formulário de recuperação
let formForgot = document.getElementById('forgot-form')

// evento no link para recuperação
forgot.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    // esconder este formulário
    formSignin.classList.add('hide')
    // mostrar o outro formulário
    formForgot.classList.remove('hide')
}, true)

// evento no link para login
signin.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    // esconder este formulário
    formForgot.classList.add('hide')
    // mostrar o outro formulário
    formSignin.classList.remove('hide')
}, true)
```

```css
.hide {
    display: none!important;
}
```

```html
<!-- formulário padrão -->
<form id="signin-form" action="#">
    <fieldset>
        <legend class="title"><span class="lang" key = "LogIn">SING IN</span></legend>
        <div class="input_block">
            <div class="input_wrap">
                <input type="text" id="mail" class="input" placeholder="Email">
                <label for="mail" class="label_mail"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="input_wrap">
                <input type="text" id="pass" class="input" placeholder="Password">
                <label for="pass" class="label_pass"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="forgotPass" id="forgot"><span class="lang" key ="ForgotPassword">Forgot password</span>?</a>
        <input type="submit" value="Sing IN" class="btn btn_red">
    </fieldset>
</form>

<!-- formulário "escondido" -->
<form id="forgot-form" class="hide" action="#">
    <fieldset>
        <legend class="title"><span class="lang" key = "SendmePassword">Send me password</span></legend>
            <div class="input_block">
                <div class="input_wrap">
                    <input type="text" id="sing_email" class="input" placeholder="Email">
                    <label for="sing_email" class="label_mail"></label>
                </div>
                <p>Enter a valid e-mail, the password will be sent to you  </p>
            </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn_red" id="backtoSingIN">Sing IN</button>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btnSend btn_red" id="send">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

No seu exemplo original a ação de "voltar" esta condicionada há um `<input type="submit">` ... tomei a liberdade de modificar para um elemento de botão `<button>` porque o formulário de recuperação já possuí um `submit`.

Basicamente utilize `CSS` e uma classe para ocultar e adicione e remova esta classe entre os formulários.

Eu utilizei a propriedade `.classList` para adicionar e remover a classe dos formulários, navegadores legados (como IE 9 e anteriores) podem precisar de um **"polyfill"** ou use jQuery para tal.

Se por algum motivo não podes renderizar seus formulários por padrão e só pode adicioná-los dinamicamente, chame seus ouvintes de evento após adicioná-los ao documento e preferencialmente adicione ambos com esta lógica: **um visível (o padrão) e outro oculto**.

O seguinte exemplo expressa isto:

```js
let ModelSignin = `
<!-- formulário padrão -->
<form id="signin-form" action="#">
    <fieldset>
        <legend class="title"><span class="lang" key = "LogIn">SING IN</span></legend>
        <div class="input_block">
            <div class="input_wrap">
                <input type="text" id="mail" class="input" placeholder="Email">
                <label for="mail" class="label_mail"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="input_wrap">
                <input type="text" id="pass" class="input" placeholder="Password">
                <label for="pass" class="label_pass"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="forgotPass" id="forgot"><span class="lang" key ="ForgotPassword">Forgot password</span>?</a>
        <input type="submit" value="Sing IN" class="btn btn_red">
    </fieldset>
</form>`

let ModelForgot = `
<!-- formulário "escondido" -->
<form id="forgot-form" class="hide" action="#">
    <fieldset>
        <legend class="title"><span class="lang" key = "SendmePassword">Send me password</span></legend>
            <div class="input_block">
                <div class="input_wrap">
                    <input type="text" id="sing_email" class="input" placeholder="Email">
                    <label for="sing_email" class="label_mail"></label>
                </div>
                <p>Enter a valid e-mail, the password will be sent to you  </p>
            </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn_red" id="backtoSingIN">Sing IN</button>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btnSend btn_red" id="send">
    </fieldset>
</form>`

// renderize os formulários e após chame seus ouvintes
function RenderForms() {
    // adicione os formulários ha um elemento
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', ModelSignin + ModelForgot)

    // trate os eventos em seus formulários

    let forgot = document.getElementById("forgot")
    let signin = document.getElementById('backtoSingIN')
    let formSignin = document.getElementById('signin-form')
    let formForgot = document.getElementById('forgot-form')

    // evento no link para recuperação
    forgot.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
        // esconder este formulário
        formSignin.classList.add('hide')
        // mostrar o outro formulário
        formForgot.classList.remove('hide')
    }, true)

    // evento no link para login
    signin.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
        // esconder este formulário
        formForgot.classList.add('hide')
        // mostrar o outro formulário
        formSignin.classList.remove('hide')
    }, true)
}

// chame a função de renderização quando quiser
RenderForms()
```

```css
.hide{
  display:none!important;
}
```

No exemplo acima eu utilizei `document.body` como elemento (container) para adicionar ambos os formulários e o método `.insertAdjacentHTML()`, você pode utilizar qualquer elemento de sua escolha como "container".

---

**Referencias**:

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

`.classList` polyfill: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Polyfill

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, e pelos detalhes na explicação :)